# why is my rails scope query on jsonb not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql, jsonb

I have a **jsonb** column with default {}, added the key `"home_page":"1"` (update_attribute and save...).

I added a scope to the model -

`scope :home_page, -> { where("my_column ->> 'home_page' = ?", "1") }`

no matter what I do I'm always getting an empty result.

help :(

rails - 5.2.2, 
ruby - 2.5, 
db - PostgreSQL 10.3

Comment: Are you sure you actually set the default properly with `t.jsonb :my_column, default: -> { "'{}'::jsonb" }`? And that you´re not messing up the example in some other way? I tried replicating the issue and I'm getting the expected results.

Comment: `add_column :my_table, :my_column, :jsonb, default: {}` - is it wrong?

Comment: No thats correct.

Comment: so wtf is wrong here?!?! can't get it...

Answer (score 0):

Your scope **is working**.

```
class Thing < ApplicationRecord
  scope :home_page, -> { where("my_column ->> 'home_page' = ?", "1") }
end
```

As shown by this passing spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Thing, type: :model do
  after(:each) { Thing.destroy_all }
  describe '.home_page' do
    it "includes records with home_page: 1" do
      thing = Thing.create(my_column: { home_page: 1 })
      expect(Thing.home_page).to include thing
    end

    it "includes records with home_page: '1'" do
      thing = Thing.create(my_column: { home_page: '1' })
      expect(Thing.home_page).to include thing
    end

    it "does not return records that do not match the criteria" do
      Thing.create(my_column: { home_page: 0 })
      Thing.create(my_column: { xhome_page: 1 })
      expect(Thing.home_page).to be_empty
    end
  end
end
```

Rather the error is in your test methodology or the setup. For example you can try calling `.save!` to see if there are any validation errors.

Comment: Hi,  the scope does work, the problem is that it always return an empty result.

Comment: Then you dont have any records that match the scope